# potential inside a cylindrical shell in terms of the surface potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, classical-electrodynamics

Given a potential distribution $V(\phi)$ at the surface of an infinite cylindrical shell, is there an easy way to derive the potential inside the cylinder. No charges or currents anywhere.

Comment: It's hard to know what "easy" means to you.  There is more than one way to do this 1) Determine the Green's function for the Dirichlet problem on the interior of the cylinder and then compute an integral 2) Expand the the potential in appropriate orthogonal functions (involving Bessel functions in this case), and compute the coefficients in the expansion by doing some integrals.  If the potential is sufficiently simple, both of these methods shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no charges inside the cylinder, then the potential obeys Laplace's Equation:

$$\nabla^2V = 0$$

In cylindrical coordinates, that's

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac 1 r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right) V = 0$$

Based on your notation, it seems like your potential doesn't vary in the z-direction, so that can be simplified to

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac 1 r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}\right) V(r, \phi) = 0$$

This is a differential equation for your potential inside the cylinder that you'll need to solve for your boundary condition $V(\phi)$ - there are a lot of techniques out there for doing that.